# getApplicationBanner returns null

Tags: android, android-tv, android-launcher

I am working on a customized android launcher for a setupbox and trying to get the banner of the tv applications (the ones seen in the image below) using 
`packageInfo.applicationInfo.loadBanner(context.getPackageManager());` 
OR
`context.getPackageManager().getApplicationBanner(packageName)`

[image: Android tv apps]
It is working for most apps, however some of them returns null as a result, For example Google Play Games, although i can get the icon (which is the logo without the text beside it).

Am I using the correct api? Is there anyway to get it programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also having that problem. The reason app developers didn`t attach banner to package is because they attach banner to activity.

Sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="ru.tv1.android.tv">
    ......
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="ru.kino1tv.android.tv.App" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Leanback">
        <activity android:banner="@drawable/app_icon_banner" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon_banner" android:label="@string/app_name" android:logo="@drawable/app_icon_banner" android:name="ru.kino1tv.android.tv.ui.activity.MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable" android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
       ......

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Every package can have few launch activities. So, you need first try to load banner for activity, and then if it's `null` try to load the banner for package.

```
Intent AppsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
AppsIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LEANBACK_LAUNCHER);
List<ResolveInfo> apps = mPackageManager.queryIntentActivities(AppsIntent, 0);

for (ResolveInfo app : apps) {
    Drawable banner = app.activityInfo.loadBanner(mPackageManager);
    if (banner == null) {
        banner = app.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadBanner(mPackageManager);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks it finally works! but any idea how can i get the intent for a specified package without looping through all of them

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [getApplicationBanner](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getApplicationBanner(java.lang.String)) method:

> added in API level 20
>
> public abstract Drawable `getApplicationBanner` (String packageName)
>
> Retrieve the banner associated with an application. Given the name of
>   the application's package, retrieves the information about it and
>   calls `getApplicationIcon()` **to return its banner**. If the application
>   cannot be found, `NameNotFoundException` is thrown.

Your function should also calls the `getApplicationIcon` to return its banner after calling the `getApplicationBanner` method.

Comment: I am using `getApplicationIcon` after `getApplicationBanner` in case the banner is null which is returning the icon as expected. But i want the banner and not the icon

Comment: It says from the documentation that you must also call the 'getApplicationIcon' to return its banner.

Comment: what i understood from the documentation that `getApplicationBanner` will call  `getApplicationIcon` but anyway am calling it and same result